# Saving file in Android using Xamarin

Tags: c#, winforms, xamarin.android

In a C# WinForm app I'm using the exact same code to download a file from a website that uses FTPS protocol.

However, when I port the code to a Xamarin Android app the code fails with the following error msg.

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/C:\Projects\DownloadFileTest1\DownloadFileTest1\bin\debug\Grid2.txt" is denied.

The error occurs on  the following line:

```
 FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
```

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
 private static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void DownloadFile()
    {
        tv.Text = "In DownloadFile";
        string fileName = @"C:\Projects\DownloadFileTest1\DownloadFileTest1\bin\debug\Grid2.txt";
        var interval = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
        var uri = new Uri("ftp://ftp.xxxxxx.com/Grid2.txt");

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ValidateServerCertificate;

        //try
        //{
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        request.EnableSsl = true;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("temp1@xxxxx.com", "Temp1#");
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        int dataLength = (int)request.GetResponse().ContentLength;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
        int ReadCount = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        while (ReadCount > 0)
        {
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, ReadCount);
            ReadCount = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        //      ResponseDescription = response.StatusDescription;
        fs.Close();
        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
```

}

I've spent a couple days with this bug and learning Xamarin at the same time. I'd like to get it working in a Xamarin Forms app with UWP as well.

Comment: You're trying to read/write to C: on Android?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something meaningful that describes the problem you're having or the question you're asking. You've simply repeated the information that is already available in the tags, and if you remove that information your title has zero content. The title should be descriptive enough to have meaning to future readers who see it in a search result. (And as @Aquinas has said, Android doesn't have a C: drive or use backslashes in paths. Perhaps before you try writing Android apps you should learn something about the OS.)